# Use PHP to create list of WHM accounts

Tags: php, account, whm

I would like to know if it is possible to connect to my WHM with PHP using the **cPanel PublicAPI PHP Repository** https://github.com/CpanelInc/publicapi-php so that I can create a list of the accounts in the WHM.

Is there anything I should know? Are there any restrictions? I simply want to populate a list of my accounts that are in my WHM.

Right now I'm getting an error

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
```

I was wondering if there was something blocking me?

Here is what my code looks like, I'd like to create a php variable to holds the array data, then loop through it printing the account domain name

```
require_once '../_libraries/publicapi-php-master/Cpanel/Util/Autoload.php';
$config = array(
    'service' => array(
        'whm' => array(
            'config'    => array(
                'host' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'user' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXX'
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$cp = Cpanel_PublicAPI::getInstance($config);
$accounts = $cp->whm_api('listaccts');
print_R($accounts);
#print $accounts->_response->dataContainer->storage->acct->dataContainer->storage[0];
```

When I do a print_r($accounts) this is what I get, I just need to know how to traverse this and loop through it with PHP. I can see in this output the first domain is cfpacking.com, that is the data I'm after.

```
Cpanel_Query_Object Object
(
    [_query:Cpanel_Query_Object:private] => Cpanel_Core_Object Object
        (
            [dataContainer:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                            [adapter] => whostmgr
                            [client] => curl
                            [url] => https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:2087/json-api/listaccts
                            [args] => 
                            [argsArray] => Cpanel_Core_Object Object
                                (
                                    [dataContainer:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                                        (
                                            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [authstr] => Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==

                            [directURL] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [_response:Cpanel_Query_Object:private] => Cpanel_Core_Object Object
        (
            [dataContainer:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => 1
                            [statusmsg] => Ok
                            [acct] => Cpanel_Core_Object Object
                                (
                                    [dataContainer:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                                        (
                                            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Cpanel_Core_Object Object
                                                        (
                                                            [dataContainer:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [inodeslimit] => 500000
                                                                            [ip] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                                                            [mailbox_format] => maildir
                                                                            [plan] => default
                                                                            [maxftp] => unlimited
                                                                            [maxparked] => unlimited
                                                                            [owner] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                                                            [maxpop] => unlimited
                                                                            [email] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                                                            [max_email_per_hour] => 500
                                                                            [disklimit] => unlimited
                                                                            [maxlst] => unlimited
                                                                            [min_defer_fail_to_trigger_protection] => 5
                                                                            [backup] => 1
                                                                            [startdate] => 17 Dec 27 15:59
                                                                            [inodesused] => 3281
                                                                            [maxsql] => unlimited
                                                                            [max_defer_fail_percentage] => 25
                                                                            [ipv6] => Cpanel_Core_Object Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [dataContainer:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                )

                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [max_emailacct_quota] => unlimited
                                                                            [maxsub] => unlimited
                                                                            [unix_startdate] => 1514411971
                                                                            [outgoing_mail_hold] => 0
                                                                            [partition] => home
                                                                            [legacy_backup] => 1
                                                                            [maxaddons] => unlimited
                                                                            [suspendtime] => 0
                                                                            [uid] => 1750
                                                                            [suspendreason] => not suspended
                                                                            [suspended] => 0
                                                                            [user] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                                                            [domain] => cfpacking.com
                                                                            [diskused] => 79M
                                                                            [theme] => paper_lantern
                                                                            [temporary] => 0
                                                                            [is_locked] => 0
                                                                            [shell] => /bin/bash
                                                                            [outgoing_mail_suspended] => 0
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Cpanel_Core_Object Object
```

Comment: On what line does that error occur? Could you show any relevant code?

Comment: publicapi-php-master/Cpanel/PublicAPI.php on line 343 Also I should note that at this moment I really don't know what I'm doing, just what I'm trying to achieve. I just need some examples. The API is hard for me to understand. It shows what you can do but not how to do it.

Comment: Could you show the code that you have tried?(Excluding the username/password ofcourse!) This way we can help achieve your goal

Comment: added code, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response object can be turned into an array using the following syntax:

```
require_once '../_libraries/publicapi-php-master/Cpanel/Util/Autoload.php';
$config = array(
    'service' => array(
        'whm' => array(
            'config'    => array(
                'host' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'user' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$cp = Cpanel_PublicAPI::getInstance($config);
$accounts = $cp->whm_api('listaccts',array('search'=>'XXXXXXXXX','searchtype'=>'owner'));
$accounts = $accounts->getResponse('array')['acct'];

foreach($accounts as $account){
    print $account['domain'];
    print '<br />';
}
```

The library(https://github.com/CpanelInc/publicapi-php) contains code that generates warnings in php 7.2 because of a [breaking change](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types). Because the library hasn't been maintaned for 9 years you will have to fix it yourself.

The fix:
old:

> Cpanel/PublicApi.php line 343

```
if (count($storedServicesConfig) > 1) {
```

new:

> Cpanel/PublicApi.php line 343

```
if (count($storedServicesConfig->getAllData()) > 1) {
```

Comment: Getting error Notice: Trying to get property 'acct' of non-object

Comment: Also, I do not see the info you are referencing there. I search the page for that and nothing came up.

Comment: Is there any output if you use `var_dump($accounts);`? @drooh

Comment: yes, it shows me a whole slew of data, just not sure how to traverse that. Will add to my question at top.

Comment: Could you add the result of `var_dump($accounts);` with the snippet from the updated answer to your question? Be sure to exclude the personal data!   @drooh

Comment: What is the output for `var_dump($accounts);`? @drooh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198780/discussion-between-maartendev-and-drooh).